# check shared preference value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to check the value in `editext` every time app is launched. I'm using shared preference to store `edittext` value user entered the first time app was launched. The next time app is launched if the value in `edittext` is same as saved shared preference value then instead of showing that activity, app skips it and displays the next activity. Prob is even if the value is correct in  `edittext`, app is not skipping that activity. I think the comparing values might be incorrect.

**MainActivity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity{

    EditText et;
    int keyDel;
    String tempString;
    char[] stringArray;

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
    public static final String PIN = "passKey";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginactivity);

        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

///////////////////////////////////// Shared Preference Code Starts /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(PIN)) {
            et.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(PIN, ""));
        }

        String chk_et = et.getText().toString();
        if(chk_et == sharedpreferences.getString(PIN, "")){
            startActivity( new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Welcome.class));
            finish();

            //finish();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } 

///////////////////////////////////// Shared Preference Code Ends ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   

///////////////////////////////////// Text Watcher Code Starts //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 et.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                              if(keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && et.getText().length() !=0)
                                {
                                    if(et.getText().length()==4 ||et.getText().length()==8)
                                    {                             
                                        tempString=et.getText().toString()+"-";
                                        char c=tempString.charAt(tempString.length()-2);

                                        if(c!='-')
                                        {
                                            stringArray = tempString.toCharArray();                    
                                            stringArray[tempString.length()-2]=stringArray[tempString.length()-1];
                                            stringArray[tempString.length()-1]=c;

                                            //code to convert charArray back to String..
                                            tempString=new String(stringArray);
                                            et.setText(tempString);             
                                            et.setSelection(tempString.length());
                                            tempString=null;
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                                return false ;   
                        }
                    });


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

///////////////////////////////////// Text Watcher Code Ends //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////     
    } // onCreate ends

    public void Save(View view) {
        String et_new = et.getText().toString();
        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(PIN, et_new);
        editor.commit();
    }

} // Activity ends
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't compare String objects with the `==` operator.

When using `==`, you're essentially checking if both references are pointing to the same String object in the heap.

What you should do is compare String with the `equals()` method, which compares the content of the String.

Answer (score 0):

This logic makes no sense:

```
if (sharedpreferences.contains(PIN)) {
            et.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(PIN, ""));
        }

        String chk_et = et.getText().toString();
        if(chk_et == sharedpreferences.getString(PIN, "")){
            startActivity( new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Welcome.class));
            finish();

            //finish();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Read the documentation!

P.S. It is better to compare String values with equals() method.

Comment: @Victor, I'm checking with this logic that the edittext value is same as value stored in shared preference or not. Anyway thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @SomnathPal: Right, but you shouldn't use `==` to compare string. Use `equals()` method to compare a string.

Comment: @Victor. Got it. Using equals() method skips the layout as I wanted. But the problem is even after I uninstall the app the app skips the activity. It should not skip the activity as sharedpreference value gets cleared after app is uninstalled.

Comment: @Viktor. So, is the code correct? I just want to compare present edittext value to the stored sharedpreference value.

Comment: To clear shared prefs you need to clear app data, it doesn't remove if you uninstalled your app. Go to settings->apps-> select your app-> clear data

Comment: It makes no sense, cause you comparing value to itself. if I get you right than you need to check whether your preference is not empty at start up and other method to compare value from editText to one from prefs.

Comment: Yes, I want on first installation for user to enter a 9 digit PIN and save it in preference. When user opens app second time, it checks if the edittext have the same value as stored in preference and if yes, skips the editext layout completely and go to next layout.

Comment: So, any suggestion on how to compare?

Comment: why do you need to put something to edittext if you want to skip that part? As I wrote it before just check TextUtils.isEmpty(sharedpreferences.getString(PIN, "")) if true then show your layout and do all do you want here if false then move to next activity

Comment: The idea of checking the content of an EditText on Activity launch to check if the user is logged in is ... strange, to put it nicely :)